# Use button to edit highlighted/selected row of a table view

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form the displays a datasheet of information from a table in MS Access. What I would like to do is to implement a button to edit some of the information of the highlight/selected field.

I am not sure how I would get the selected row's "information" like `ID` and `Name` and how to make edits to the row. Or if there is a VBA command to perform actions on the selected row.

I know the SQL I want to run on the row but don't know how to go about selecting the row and its fields to edit.

```
Private Sub Command159_Click()
    ssql = "UPDATE [activity_submissions_tb] SET [Edit] = True" & _
    "WHERE [submissionID] = " & [HIGHLIGHTED FIELD].submissionID
    DoCmd.RunSQL ssql
End Sub
```

The following edits all rows in the table. The `WHERE` clause does not work as I am not sure how to grab the `ID` of the selected row or if there is a current row command. Here is a picture of what the form looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC8wC.jpg.

Any help would be appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: Since you are in datasheet view already why are you unable to make changes directly? Do you want to open a form to edit the row because you are only showing some data in datasheet view but you have many more fields people could edit?

Comment: @Brad The data is displayed in the form view. I want to be able to edit the selected row without going into the datasheet view. [Example Picture](http://imgur.com/a/kmiF7) It looks a little something like this where the button makes changes to the selected row.

Comment: You're displaying your data in a listbox? Is that right? Hard to tell if that is a formatted datasheet or a listbox in that picture.

Comment: @Brad The form is pulling a query to display the datasheet in the form [Better Picture](http://imgur.com/a/EIj9B)

Comment: @Brad and yes there is only some data being shown in the form and several more fields that can be edited.

Comment: @Brad I added some more information in the initial question.

Comment: Hey sorry, I'll take a look tomorrow if I can (got busy here). Good luck until then

Comment: What do you want to edit in the fields? You can edit them directly without SQL just by using a button on the same form.  The vba will recognize the selected row and you can make changes directly to the visible (or invisible) fields

Comment: If you were hoping that you could make just the selected row editable.. i don't think it's possible. You can however toggle editing of the fields in the whole datasheet. Also, are you sure you've got the `Default View` set to `Datasheet`? I didn't know you could apply custom colours to datasheets..

Comment: @dbmitch I want to edit a field in the table of the highlighted row. In this case I want to set `Edit` to Yes for the highlighted row. The SQL query updates all rows without the `WHERE` clause. I need to be able to use a `WHERE` clause to pinpoint the exact row that is currently highlighted.

Comment: @MattHall The default view is Form View it is just showing fields from a table/datasheet in form view. I want to edit the specific row highlighted not make only that row editable if that makes sense. I can toggle the Yes/No fields of `EDIT` IN the datasheet view but I have heard it is practical for updates to be made in form view rather than datasheet view.

Comment: @Brad Yes this is a List Box I only figure it out now. Is there a way to select the highlighted field knowing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out it was a ListBox I could use `ME![ListboxName]` to edit the current highlighted item.

```
Private Sub Command159_Click()
    ssql = "UPDATE [activity_submissions_tb] SET [Edit] = True" & _
    "WHERE [submissionID] = " & Me![PromoLoaded]
    DoCmd.RunSQL ssql
End Sub
```

Thanks to everyone that helped.

Comment: This is dependent on the `Bound Column` setting of the listbox.